# Как получить пользователей с последними комментариями в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Написать SQL запрос к СУБД MySQL, который выберет из базы имена пользователей и их последние комментарии (по одному комментарию на каждого пользователя), при следующей структуре таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `db_user` (
`db_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`db_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `db_comment` (
`db_comment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`db_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`text` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`db_comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

У  меня такой вариант решения, подойдёт ли он ?

```
SELECT db_user.name, db_comment.text
from db_user
left join  db_comment 
on db_user.db_user_id = db_comment.db_user_id
WHERE db_comment.db_comment_id = (SELECT MAX(db_comment.db_comment_id) FROM db_comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее решение.

`SELECT` с участием `ROW_NUMBER()` внутри CTE предоставит способ найти последний комментарий на каждого пользователя.

**SQL**

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
       db_user_id,
       text,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY db_user_id  
          ORDER BY db_comment_id DESC) row_num
    FROM db_comment 
)
SELECT db_user.name, cte.text
FROM db_user left outer join cte 
    on db_user.db_user_id = cte.db_user_id 
WHERE COALESCE(cte.row_num, 1) = 1;
```